# Jest test react hook method to get better code coverage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component, that sets state based on the onClick method as follows:

```
const [active, setActive] = React.useState(0);

<button type="button" onClick={() => {setActive(() => index); inner.fc(index)}} key={inner.id}>{inner.title}</button>
```

The test itself is:

```
it('Should test setActive index of button', (): void => {
    const setIndex = jest.fn(() => 1);
    let tree = create(<button type="button" onClick={setIndex} key='1'>1 button</button>);
    const button = tree.root.findByType('button')
    button.props.onClick()
    expect(setIndex()).toBe(1);
});
```

This passes but when I look at the coverage report, it flags the setActive method as not covered? How do I test that React.useState method correctly?

Comment: Why you are passing an arrow function to a hook? Shouldn't be `setActive(index)`?

Comment: That does not really impact the test though, I have set state that way before when using  numbers etc. Why would you not do that?

Comment: Because, usually, I always passed a variable into an hook, never a function BUT I'm not so expert to say "you can't do that" so... I will continue my investigation and if I found something I will answer to you. Thank you for your explanation.